# Merge js files into one with phpStorm

Tags: javascript, node.js, merge, phpstorm

Using phpStorm, I would like to merge multiple JavaScript files into one.
I installed the closure compiler and configured the file watcher to minify each JavaScript file.

Now, I would like to combine all of my JavaScript files into one.

Here's the architecture of my project (a test project to merge js files) :

```
index.php
js(folder) >
    first.js (+first.min.js),
    second.js (+second.min.js),
    third.js (+third.min.js)
cache (folder)
    main.js
```

I would like to merge (first.min.js, second.min.js, third.min.js) into folder `cache > main.js`.

Ideally, merging all of the files would happen automatically; I don't want to specify each js file manually.

Can someone explain the arguments I must use to configure my filewatcher?

Comment: I'd suggest creating a shell script that would merge all your min.js files into a specified file (see https://github.com/benjaminwy/js.sh, for example) and configure it as a file watcher in WebStorm so that it listens to changes in minified files

Comment: I dont'understand how I can configure it with phpStorm ... Could you help me ?

Comment: create a new file watcher for javascript files, set a full path to your shell script as a program. If your shell script expects some parameters, add them to 'arguments' field. Set a pattern for script output in 'output path to refresh'. Also, make sure to create a custom scope with only your minified files included and choose this scope as your file watcher scope.

Comment: Configure [Webpack](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/webpack.html) and I recommend using Webpack Encore to create the config file.

Answer (score 0):

I used npm plugins `concat`, `minifier` and `walk`.

Here is the script I made :

```
var walk = require('walk'),
    concat = require('concat'),
    minifier = require('minifier'),
    files = [];

var JS_SOURCES_DIR = 'app/components',
    JS_LAST_FILE = 'app/app.module.js',
    JS_DIR = 'app/',
    JS_FULL_FILE = JS_DIR + 'app.js',
    JS_MINIFIED_FILE = 'app.min.js',
    JS_MINIFIED_FILE_PATH = JS_DIR + JS_MINIFIED_FILE;

var walker = walk.walk(JS_SOURCES_DIR, {followLinks: false});

walker.on('file', (root, stat, next) => {
    var fullpath = root.replace(/\\/g, '/');
    var regex = new RegExp(/.+\.js$/);
    if (stat.name.match(regex)) {
        files.push(fullpath + '/' + stat.name);
    }
    next();
});

walker.on('end', function () {
    files.push(JS_LAST_FILE);
    files.forEach(function (item) {
        console.log(item);
    })
    concat(files, JS_FULL_FILE).then((result) => {
        minifier.minify(JS_FULL_FILE, {output: JS_MINIFIED_FILE_PATH});
        console.log('\n[OK] ' + JS_MINIFIED_FILE + ' sucessfully updated');
    }, function (error) {
        console.log('[ERROR] JS concat failure: ' + error.message);
    });
});

minifier.on('error', function (error) {
    console.log('\n[ERROR] JS minify error: ' + error);
});
```

First with walker, files are added to var "files". I used JS_LAST_FILE for angularjs concerns, as I build the module and add all the dependencies in that file. Then files are concatenated to JS_FULL_FILE. Finally JS_FULL_FILE is minified to JS_MINIFIED_FILE.

I do not use a watcher to trigger the concat script when a file is updated.
Instead when I work locally, I don't concatenate files but I simply add them in the `head` part of the page using a homemade function that uses php scandir().